# principiante en java

Tags: java

Tengo esta expresión y no me corre

```
package clase;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClasePrincipal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int veces = 0;
        String nombre = "";
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingresa un nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("¿Cuantas veces deseas imprimir el nombre? ");
        veces = entrada.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i >= veces; i++) {

            System.out.println("hola " + nombre);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Qué error te da? y qué quieres que te de? danos una introducción para poder ayudar

Comment: A simple vista tienes mal el for , creo que deberia ser `for (int i = 0; i <= veces; i++)`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No te corre, que quiere decir? no funciona? tira un error? hace algo que tiene que hacer, y no lo hace? podrias ser mucho mas claro?

Comment: El error esta en tu ciclo for, en la parte de la condición cambia esta parte `i>=veces` por `i<=veces`.

Comment: Porque en vez de arle negativo no lo retroalimentan? Que mierda les pasa a los programadores y su ego arrogante.... el es nuevo, lo peor que pueden hacer es ser asi de destructivos. Esta comunidad es mala por el simple echo de su gente.

Comment: @itsvanmoreno lo mas probable es que lo hayan votado negativo por esta razón [Porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como he dicho en mi comentario.

El error se encuentra en el for, ya que este comprueba si i(que la inicias a 0) es **mayor o igual** que veces que ya con que pongas que lo haga una vez no te va a funcionar.

Mi solucion seria cambiar el signo a "<"  en lugar de ">" :

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= veces; i++) {

        System.out.println("hola " + nombre);
    }
```

Otra observacion es que si pones el "=" vas a imprimir una vez mas el mensaje (y eso no lo quieres :D)

Por ejemplo si pones 2 veces con "<=" te saldra lo siguiente:

```
Ingresa un nombre: Victor
¿Cuantas veces deseas imprimir el nombre? 2
hola Victor
hola Victor
hola Victor
```

Comment: mas alla de eso, y de que sea principiante, seria bueno aclarar que todo ese codigo no tiene mucho sentido. ni como un ejercicio de aprendizaje...

Comment: Tu sugiero ayudes al usuario a modificar su pregunta, de lo contrario solo será de ayuda para el y no para la comunidad, las preguntas deben basarse en [help].